# Python Scheduler - Adjust time interval on-the-fly

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

I am utilizing the `Python Advanced Scheduler` library and what I would like to happen is to change the time interval on-the-fly, however this doesn't seem to be working with my implementation. What I am doing is setting the time interval based on what the current `model_retrain_freq` Manager member value is, then using the public setter to change that interval at a later time. The later time is never picked up. Suggestions? Please refer to the following:

run.py

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
import atexit

from app.main.manager import Manager

manager = Manager()

sched = BackgroundScheduler(daemon=True)
sched.add_job(
    manager.model_expiry_callback,
    "interval",
    seconds=manager.model_retrain_freq,
)
sched.start()
atexit.register(lambda: sched.shutdown(wait=False))

# testing
import time

time.sleep(10)
manager.model_retrain_freq = 1

time.sleep(9000)
```

manager.py

```
class Manager:
 def __init__(self):
        self._model_retrain_freq = 5

@property
def model_retrain_freq(self):
    """Get model retrain frequency"""
    return self._model_retrain_freq

@model_retrain_freq.setter
def model_retrain_freq(self, value):
    """Set model retrain frequency"""
    self._model_retrain_freq = value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the value of `_model_retrain_freq` will not affect the job that was created. You will need to reschedule the job after changing `_model_retrain_freq`.

Store the job that is created.

```
job = sched.add_job(
    manager.model_expiry_callback,
    "interval",
    seconds=manager.model_retrain_freq,
)
```

When you need to reschedule it after changing the value of `_model_retrain_freq`:

```
job.reschedule(trigger="interval", seconds=manager.model_retrain_freq)
```

Comment: Understood. Thank you for the reply and your given solution.